# Storing variable on service onDestroy at device restart

Tags: android, service, background-process

When the phone is turned off and restarts. I want to store some data on my shared preferences. I want to do this on my serivce onDestroy. But it doesn't seem to be storing when I restart my phone or turned it off and on again. Here's how I do it. Again, this is a service.

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    preferences = getSharedPreferences(pref_data, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    driverPassword = preferences.getString("driverPassword","");
    carrierId = preferences.getString("carrierId","");
    cctid = preferences.getString("CCTID","");
    shipment = preferences.getString("shipment","");

    try
    {
        JSONObject shipmentObject = new JSONObject(shipment);
        shipmentID = shipmentObject.getString("ShipmentId");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

    }

     powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
     wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,
                "MyWakeLock");


     handler.removeCallbacks(sendWakeLock);
     handler.postDelayed(sendWakeLock, 1000); // 1 second   
     Log.w("onStart", "onStart");

     return  Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.w("onDestroy", "onDestroy");
    handler.removeCallbacks(sendWakeLock);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putString("isDriverLogin", "True");
    editor.putString("driverPassword", driverPassword);
    editor.putString("carrierId", carrierId);
    editor.putString("CCTID", cctid);
    editor.putString("shipment", shipment);
    editor.putString("isAccepted", "");
    editor.putString("newshipment", "");
    editor.putString("isRemoved", "True");
    editor.commit();
}
```

Note: I have other important activities on my activity's onDestroy method and I don't want to use it. I want to utilize the event that happens to my service if the phone is restarted. I also set Service.START_NOT_STICKY; Hoping that when the phone restarts or turned off, it will execute my onDestroy. Any ideas on how I should catch the event on my service when the phone is restarted or my service is stopped when I restart my phone?

Answer (score 0):

Under newer versions, a service will have the following events triggered:

```
onCreate()
Followed by...

int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startid)
```

// Determine if one of my services is currently running

```
public static boolean isMyServiceRunning(Context context, String servicename) {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (servicename.equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I don't actually get how could I implement this on my situation. As soon as my service is destroyed I want to store values. How can I check if my service is running if I restart my phone?